# Path must be a string and POST localserver 500 internet server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

What I am trying to do is simple training server app with CRUD functions.
I succeeded with that I can edit or delete already existing users, but stuck on trying to solve how actually to create and add to existing users.json file another one. I am sure that I am missing something.

Git repo for full directory: https://gitlab.com/alexgnatrow/practice-nodejs

Here is the main index.js.

```
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const path = require('path');

    const fs = require('fs');
    const _ = require('lodash');
    const engines = require('consolidate');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 


let users = [];

function getUser(username) {
    let user = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(getUserFilePath(username), {encoding: 'utf8'}));
    user.nickname = user.name.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/ig, '');

    return user
}

function getUserFilePath(username) {
    return `${path.join(__dirname, 'users', username)}.json`
}

function createUser(username, data){
    let fp = getUserFilePath(username);
    let string =  JSON.stringify(data, null , 2);
    console.log(string);
    fs.writeFileSync(fp, string , {encoding: 'utf8'})
}

function saveUser(username, data) {
    let fp = getUserFilePath(username);
    fs.unlinkSync(fp);
    console.log(data);
    fs.writeFileSync(fp, JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), {encoding: 'utf8'})
}

function verifyUser(req, res, next) {
    let username = req.params.username;
    let fp = getUserFilePath(username);

    fs.exists(fp, yes => {
        if (yes) {
            next()
        } else {
            res.redirect('/error/' + username)
        }
    })
}

app.engine('hbs', engines.handlebars);

app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');


app.use(express.static('public')); //example of serve static files
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Body parser use JSON data

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    fs.readdir('users', (err, files) => {
      if(err|| files==="favicon.ico"){console.log('there is no need to create a fucking favicon');}
        files = _.filter(files, file => !file.startsWith('.'));
        users = _.map(files, file => getUser(file.replace(/\.json/ig, '')));
        res.render('index', {users})
    });
});

app.get('*.json', (req, res) => res.download('./users/' + req.path));
app.get('/error/:username', (req, res) => res.status(404).send(`No user named ${req.params.username} found`));
app.get('/data/:username', (req, res) => {
    res.header("Content-Type", 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify(getUser(req.params.username), null, 4));
});

app.all('/:username', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.method, 'for', req.params.username);
    next()
});

app.get('/:username', verifyUser, function(req, res) {
    const user = getUser(req.params.username);
    res.render('user', {user, address: user.location})
});

app.post('/', (req,res)  => {
    createUser(req.params.name, req.body);
    console.log(req.body);
    res.end()
});

app.put('/:username', function(req, res) {
    saveUser(req.params.username, req.body);
    res.end()
});

app.delete('/:username', function(req, res) {
    fs.unlinkSync(getUserFilePath(req.params.username)); // delete the file
    res.sendStatus(200)
});

const server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Server running at http://localhost:' + server.address().port)
});
```

the index.hbs with html page where i am trying to add a user:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

const fs = require('fs');
const _ = require('lodash');
const engines = require('consolidate');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


let users = [];

function getUser(username) {
    let user = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(getUserFilePath(username), {encoding: 'utf8'}));
    user.nickname = user.name.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/ig, '');

    return user
}

function getUserFilePath(username) {
    return `${path.join(__dirname, 'users', username)}.json`
}

function createUser(username, data){
    let fp = getUserFilePath(username);
    let string =  JSON.stringify(data, null , 2);
    console.log(string);
    fs.writeFileSync(fp, string , {encoding: 'utf8'})
}

function saveUser(username, data) {
    let fp = getUserFilePath(username);
    fs.unlinkSync(fp);
    console.log(data);
    fs.writeFileSync(fp, JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), {encoding: 'utf8'})
}

function verifyUser(req, res, next) {
    let username = req.params.username;
    let fp = getUserFilePath(username);

    fs.exists(fp, yes => {
        if (yes) {
            next()
        } else {
            res.redirect('/error/' + username)
        }
    })
}

app.engine('hbs', engines.handlebars);

app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');


app.use(express.static('public')); //example of serve static files
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Body parser use JSON data

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    fs.readdir('users', (err, files) => {
      if(err|| files==="favicon.ico"){console.log('there is no need to create a favicon');}
        files = _.filter(files, file => !file.startsWith('.'));
        users = _.map(files, file => getUser(file.replace(/\.json/ig, '')));
        res.render('index', {users})
    });
});

app.get('*.json', (req, res) => res.download('./users/' + req.path));
app.get('/error/:username', (req, res) => res.status(404).send(`No user named ${req.params.username} found`));
app.get('/data/:username', (req, res) => {
    res.header("Content-Type", 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify(getUser(req.params.username), null, 4));
});

app.all('/:username', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.method, 'for', req.params.username);
    next()
});

app.get('/:username', verifyUser, function(req, res) {
    const user = getUser(req.params.username);
    res.render('user', {user, address: user.location})
});

app.post('/', (req,res)  => {
    createUser(req.params.name, req.body);
    console.log(req.body);
    res.end()
});

app.put('/:username', function(req, res) {
    saveUser(req.params.username, req.body);
    res.end()
});

app.delete('/:username', function(req, res) {
    fs.unlinkSync(getUserFilePath(req.params.username)); // delete the file
    res.sendStatus(200)
});

const server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Server running at http://localhost:' + server.address().port)
});
```

the error log

```
Server running at http://localhost:3000
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:28:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:501:7)
    at getUserFilePath (C:\Users\Лёша\jsDir\practice-nodejs\index.js:21:20)
    at createUser (C:\Users\Лёша\jsDir\practice-nodejs\index.js:25:14)
    at app.post (C:\Users\Лёша\jsDir\practice-nodejs\index.js:88:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Лёша\jsDir\practice-nodejs\nod
e_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Лёша\jsDir\practice-nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router
\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Лёша\jsDir\practice-nodejs\node_modules\express\
lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Лёша\jsDir\practice-nodejs\nod
e_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Лёша\jsDir\practice-nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index
.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Лёша\jsDir\practice-nodejs\node_modules
\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Лёша\jsDir\practice-nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router
\index.js:275:10)
    at C:\Users\Лёша\jsDir\practice-nodejs\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:
130:5
    at invokeCallback (C:\Users\Лёша\jsDir\practice-nodejs\node_modules\raw-body
\index.js:224:16)
    at done (C:\Users\Лёша\jsDir\practice-nodejs\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:
213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\Лёша\jsDir\practice-nodejs\node_modules\r
aw-body\index.js:273:7)
```

Comment: An _Internal Server Error_ should produce a helpful amount of logs; those logs generally point you directly to the line where the fault happens. Share these logs or we are pretty unable to help.

Comment: @MattClark https://prnt.sc/hev6at

Comment: Please [edit] the contents of the error message into the post body, please do not post screenshots of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this chunk of code, `req.params.name` is undefined :

```
app.post('/', (req,res)  => {
    createUser(req.params.name, req.body);
    console.log(req.body);
    res.end()
});
```

[`req.params` are the parameters passed to a route](http://expressjs.com/fr/api.html#req.params). (eg. `/:name`)

Perhaps you meant `req.body` (the JSON body in the `POST` payload)?

```
app.post('/', (req,res)  => {
    createUser(req.body.name, req.body);
    console.log(req.body);
    res.end()
});
```

Comment: Actually, I tested it either way, with the same result. 
However, this morning I gave it another shot and it worked!
Used req.body.name this time